# How to preserve the current url, while switching the language parameter in it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I have this default route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            });
```

So whenever i navigate to `localhost:6060/en/Home/Index` or `localhost:6060/fr/Home/Index`, the page is displayed in that language. What i want to do, is generate links for the anchor tags, which provide the language selection possiblities. This is easy, but what i'm struggling with, is how to preserve the current parameters so the user stays on the same page, while switching a language.

Comment: How are you generating anchor tags? by using `Controller.Url`'s `UrlHelper` class?  If so, why can't you just pass route values to it's `Action` method as route values directly from action method's parameters?

Comment: Yes...you should be able to do as LB2 is suggesting...and if for some reason you have trouble with it, there's always the client side via window.location.href